# Course catalog of course era using rest api

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am using open api given by course era. 
Problem is that its giving only list of 100 courses,i checked on website there are 1294 courses listed.then why it is giving 100 courses on request.

my code is

```
<?php
 $url = "https://api.coursera.org/api/courses.v1";
 $result = file_get_contents($url);
 print_r($result);
?>
```

what should i do to fetch whole course catalog and store it in mysql db

Comment: well you are a talented programmer. Hop around the pagination and parse it.

Comment: i never used api's can you provide sample https://api.coursera.org/api/courses.v1?start=300&limit=10

Comment: I would pick your favorite programming language, use a json routine. I would use c# or java. That probably won't be helping you.

Answer (score 1):

From their docs:
https://building.coursera.org/app-platform/catalog/

> To paginate through a result set, use integer start and limit query
>   parameters.
>
> ```
> curl "https://api.coursera.org/api/courses.v1?start=300&limit=10"
> ```

So just use `start` and `limit` for pagination

Answer (score 0):

The API will only return 100 records on each call. In order to get all records, you will need to call the method multiple times and concatenate/store all of the responses.

The response returns the following value, which can be used to modify the subsequent call.

```
paging":{"next":"101","total":1948},"linked":{}}
```

Which can then be used accordingly;

```
https://api.coursera.org/api/courses.v1?start=101
```

Comment: how to change start value each time in loop

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/a/31969475/2983312 except using a limit of 100 (instead of page) and adding 100 after each loop until it returns empty.

Comment: Simply call the URL again changing the value for start as shown above. The next call will return data with a 'next' value of 201

Comment: thanx alot,it worked,now i know how to paginate data made by api request

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

curl "https://api.coursera.org/api/courses.v1?start=300&limit=10"

You will need to loop through and increase the start until you do not get any more results.

[Documentation](https://building.coursera.org/app-platform/catalog/)

Comment: how can i implement in this loop,how to change start value each time